# Add routing control to another div instead of map in Leaflet

Tags: leaflet, routing, react, open-source-routing-machine

[image]I have a React app which shows bike stations on a Leaflet map. If the user clicks the station, it routes the user to that station (Leaflet routing machine). How can I add routing control div to another div?

*Routing machine component gets called everytime user clicks station, thats why appending control div to dashboard div created multiple control divs in dashboard div*

[**CODESANDBOX**](https://codesandbox.io/s/festive-sun-ip28rq)

**RoutingMachine.jsx**

```
import React from "react";
import L, { control, Map, map, routing } from "leaflet";
import { createControlComponent } from "@react-leaflet/core";
import "leaflet-routing-machine";
import 'lrm-graphhopper'
import "leaflet-routing-machine/dist/leaflet-routing-machine.css";
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { useMap } from "react-leaflet";


const CreateRoutineMachineLayer = ({ userLat, userLong, bikeLat, bikeLong }) => {
    const instance = L.Routing.control({
    waypoints: [
      L.latLng(userLat, userLong),
      L.latLng(bikeLat, bikeLong)
    ],
    lineOptions: {
      styles: [{ color: "#6FA1EC", weight: 4 }]
    },
    createMarker: function() {
      return null
    },
    router: new L.Routing.GraphHopper('deebe34a-a717-4450-aa2a-f6de3ec9b443', {
      urlParameters: {
          vehicle: 'foot'
      }}),
    show: true, //false 
    addWaypoints: false,
    routeWhileDragging: true,
    draggableWaypoints: true,
    fitSelectedRoutes: true,
    showAlternatives: false,
  })
  // const map = useMap()
  // let routeBlock = instance.onAdd(map)
  // document.querySelector('.dashboard').appendChild(routeBlock)
  
  return instance;
};

const RoutingMachine = createControlComponent(CreateRoutineMachineLayer);

export default RoutingMachine;
```

**MapComponent.jsx**

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import '../styles/MapComponent.css';
import Loader from './Loader';
import Dashboard from './Dashboard';
import { MapContainer, TileLayer, Marker, Popup, ZoomControl, Tooltip } from 'react-leaflet';
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import { fetchUserData, fetchNetworks, fetchBikeStations } from '../redux/action/';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux'
import { bikeNetwork, person, stationIcon } from './Icons';
import RoutingMachine from './RoutingMachine';
 
const MapComponent = () => {

    const dispatch = useDispatch()

    const [latitude, setLatitude] = useState(0)
    const [longitude, setLongitude] = useState(0)
    const [bikeLat, setBikeLat] = useState(null)
    const [bikeLong, setBikeLong] = useState(null)
    const [checkBikeAdress, setCheckBikeAdress] = useState(false)
    const [checkCords, setCheckCords] = useState(false)

    const countryCode = useSelector((state) => state.countryCode)
    const bikeNetworks = useSelector((state) => state.bikeNetworks.networks) || []
    const isLightMode = useSelector((state) => state.isLightMode)
    const getStations = useSelector((state) => state.getStations)
    const stations = useSelector((state) => state.bikeStations.network?.stations)

    const bikes = bikeNetworks.filter((network) => network.location.country == countryCode)

    const setBikeAdress = (station) => {
      setBikeLat(station.latitude)
      setBikeLong(station.longitude)

      setCheckBikeAdress(false)
      setCheckBikeAdress(true)
    }



    useEffect(() => {
      if(navigator.geolocation) {
          navigator.geolocation.watchPosition((position) => {
              setLatitude(position.coords.latitude)
              setLongitude(position.coords.longitude)
              setCheckCords(true)
          })
      }
    }, [])

    useEffect(async () => {
       await dispatch(fetchUserData())
       await dispatch(fetchNetworks())
    }, [])

  return (
      !checkCords ? <Loader /> :
    <MapContainer center={[latitude, longitude]} zoom={11} zoomControl={false}>
      <Dashboard latitude={latitude} longitude={longitude} />
      <TileLayer
        attribution='&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
        url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
        className={!isLightMode ? 'default-map' : 'map-tiles'}
      />
      <Marker icon={person} position={[latitude, longitude]}></Marker>

      { 
        bikes.map((bike) => (
          <Marker
          key={bike.id}
          icon={ bikeNetwork }
          position={[bike.location.latitude, bike.location.longitude]}
          eventHandlers={{click: () => dispatch(fetchBikeStations(bike.href))}}
          >
            <Popup>
              {bike.name}
            </Popup>
          </Marker>
    ))
      }
      {!getStations ? console.log('waiting...') :
        stations.map((station) => (
          <Marker
          key={station.id}
          icon={ stationIcon }
          position={[station.latitude, station.longitude]}
          eventHandlers={{click: () => setBikeAdress(station)}}
          >
            <Tooltip>
              <div style={{lineHeight: '3px'}}>
                <p className='font-weight-bold'>{station.name}</p>
                <p>{station.extra.slots} Slots</p>
                <p>{station.free_bikes} Bikes</p>
              </div>
            </Tooltip>
          </Marker>
        ))
      } 
      <ZoomControl position="topright" />
       {
         checkBikeAdress ?   <RoutingMachine userLat={latitude} userLong={longitude} bikeLat={bikeLat} bikeLong={bikeLong}/> : null
       }
        </MapContainer>
  
  )
}

export default MapComponent
```

**Dashboard.jsx**

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import '../styles/Dashboard.css'
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux'
import { toggleMode } from '../redux/action'
import ArrowRightIcon from '@mui/icons-material/ArrowRight';
import ArrowLeftIcon from '@mui/icons-material/ArrowLeft';
import { Switch } from '@mui/material';
 
function Dashboard({latitude, longitude}) {

  const dispatch = useDispatch()

  const isLightMode = useSelector((state) => state.isLightMode)
  const networks = useSelector((state) => state.bikeNetworks.networks)
  
  
  const allCountries = []
  networks.map((network) => {
    allCountries.push(network.location.city)
  })

  const [isActive, setIsActive] = useState(false)
  
  const handleSideBar = () => {
    setIsActive(!isActive)
  }

  return (
        <div className={isActive ? 'dashboard' : 'dashboard inactive'}>
           <Switch  onChange={() => {dispatch(toggleMode())}}/>
      
          <div onClick={handleSideBar} className='dashboard-arrow d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center'>
            {isActive ? <ArrowRightIcon /> : <ArrowLeftIcon/>}
          </div>
        </div>
  )
}

export default Dashboard
```

Comment: It is appending control in another div, but problem is  everytime I click the station routing component gets called and shows direction, so outer div also keep appending controls multiple times. I am writing the code in RoutingMachine.jsx, and MapComponent.jsx calls RoutingMachine.jsx when bikeAdress state is equal to true - @TomzicM

Comment: I didn't go into logic of your code, I just pointed to the answer that answers your question as it is in the title.